# Sorting a vector of pairs by first element in ascending order, and if equal, sort second element by descending order

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector of pair I want to sort.
I want to sort by first element in ascending order, and if the first element is equal, I want to sort it by descending order of the second element.

Example:

```
3 2
1 9 
0 4
3 3
```

When sorted, it has to be:

```
0 4
1 9
3 3
3 2
```

Is there any way I could achieve this in c++?

Comment: Yes, use `std::sort` with a custom comparator.

Comment: Use the `std::sort()` variant that accepts a custom comparison function (or function object, or lambda).

Answer (score 2):

Like the guys in comments said, std::sort should work fine with some lambda. Something like this I guess:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec{
    {3, 2},
    {1, 9},
    {0, 4},
    {3, 3}
};

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& l, const auto& r){
    return (l.first == r.first) ? l.second > r.second : l.first < r.first;   
});
```

Comment: `std::pair` has comparators. No need for a lambda.

Comment: @ArminMontigny yes, there is a need, because the standard comparisons will not achieve the order that the OP wants.

Comment: Ah. Ok. Second in descending order. I see. Thanks